# BASH - Assign SSH output to variable

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, variable-assignment

I've read all the threads that I could find regarding this issue that I am having, however I have not yet found a solution to my problem.

First let me say that I am currently attempting to do this work in a very restrictive environment so I do not have the option of messing with configurations or any other admin type functions.

code:

```
ssh -t username@host "sudo -u user hadoop fs -ls /"
```

running this returns the output that I am looking for, however the next line will hang and does not assign the output to the variable:

```
output=$(ssh -t username@host "sudo -u user hadoop fs -ls")
```

I have attempted any and all variations of this line that I could find. If I do an echo of the variable it just spits out a blank line. The reason for the -t option is becuase without it I was getting an error along the lines of:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: pam_authenticate: Conversation error
```

I really don't have any contingency plans if I can't get this single line to work, so if you can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you build a [mcve] -- ie. come up with a command that other people can run themselves to see the same issue?

Comment: Is it asking you for a password for that remote-root user. Have you tried creating a private key instead of a password?

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier, ...well -- if it's `sudo` rather than `ssh` doing that prompt (or otherwise bailing), then SSH key-level auth won't be of much help.

Comment: I meant, he will need to provide authentication somehow if he want to run that 'sudo' command on the other machine.

Comment: Yes, each of the commands I listed above will prompt me for a password. In the first example after entering the password I get the desired output, in the second example, it will just hang after entering the password and ctrl+C will give me a connection closed message.

Comment: It's probably "hanging" because sudo is asking for a password but you don't see the prompt because it is being captured to your variable instead of being displayed. Instead of capturing with `$()` you could try copying the output to a temp file by adding `| tee ~/output` on the very end. Then you can read the tmp file after.

Comment: @ccarton Hey man, I can make that work! I'm still confused though as to why the first command works but the second does not. In each instance I am getting a single password prompt. Just in the second case it gets hung up upon entering the password.

Comment: Thanks @ccarton for your explanation! I had started banging my head on my desk since I have been browsing Google for hours trying to get a solution! Then I read your comment and what a relief! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a shot. I was able to do it at least 10 times in a row

```
output=$(sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' $password) ssh user:@host "sudo ls");
echo $output;
```

This command is using [sshpass](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) to pass the password non interactively to the ssh command.

Comment: `echo $output` is buggy; so is `printf '%s\n' $password`. Always `echo "$output"` and `printf '%s\n' "$password"` -- otherwise a password with spaces would be split onto two separate lines, a file named `* READ * ME * NOW *` will have the `*`s replaced with new directory listings, etc. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)